# joining each line of the file with underscore

Tags: bash, sed, for

I have an input file named `test.txt` like this:

```
Homo sapiens
Mus musculus
Rat rattus rattus
```

I want to use a `for` loop here and loop through each line. Some thing like this:

```
for i in "`cat test.txt`"
do
        fn=store_name
        do something else > ${fn}.txt
done
```

Since each line has a space between names I used double quotes in `cat test.txt`. I want to make a variable `fn` which attaches `_` between these names of the lines so my `fn` becomes `Homo_sapiens` and `Mus_musculus` and if I have `Rat rattus rates` it becomes `Rat_rattus_rattus`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: [don't read lines with "for"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: I have to 2nd that comment, don't use `for` to read lines, it's just over complicating it when there are so many cleaner safer ways to do this.

Answer (score 5):

Use `tr` to transliterate a space to an underscore:

```
while read line
do
    echo ${line} | tr -s " " "_"
done < test.txt
```

Homo_sapiens
Mus_musculus
Rat_rattus_rattus

Answer (score 4):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{OFS="_";}{$1=$1; print}' test.txt
```

Using a loop:

```
while read -r line; do 
  line=${line// /_} 
  command using "$line"
done<test.txt
```

Comment: this works but I have to operate also on those underscore names within the loop

Comment: @user3138373: I've updated it to include a loop solution

Comment: @user3138373 - why would you _need_ a "loop" ? Text should never be processed via "loops".

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `sed` and read its output with a loop:

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]\+/_/g' test.txt | while IFS= read -r line; do 
    process "$line" however
done > some.output.file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick for loop that uses sed to get it done:

```
for file in $(sed "s/ /_/g" test.txt); do echo "test" > $file; done
```

Just replace the echo command with whatever it is you want to do.

I use commands like this all the time though out the day.

Answer (score -1):

Someone gave an answer with **tr** and someone else gave one with **awk**, now here's how to do it with **sed**:

```
for i in "`cat test.txt`"
do
    fn="$(echo "$i" |sed -e 's/ /_/g')"
    'do something else' > $fn.txt
done
```

Comment: My point being there are about a hundred ways to do this...and he did tag his question with "sed".

Comment: I don't understand why you are using a `for` loop instead of `while read`.  Also why are you modifying `IFS` instead of just quoting your command substitution like op has done?  Finally, you should use `$( ... )` over backticks.

Comment: [don't read lines with "for"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: Modified to use quotes instead of IFS. As for "for" vs. "while", six one way, half-a-dozen the other.  Also, nothing wrong with backticks if you have no quotes inside the command being called.

Comment: Using "for" loop instead of "while" loop also doesn't matter in this case, because we don't want to handle blank lines anyway.